# Is there a way to implement an event filter in Fullcalendar v4 using custom buttons?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am migrating from Bootstrap DateTimePicker to Fullcalendar v4 and my problem is filtering events.

With DateTimePicker, I had much more freedom to manipulate with events shown on calendar (it also seems that Fullcalendar v3 had more freedom than v4).

I can't find a method that would just place events from array to screen. So far, this is how my code looks

```
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(element, {
                plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'interaction', 'bootstrap' ],
                themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
                events : function(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
                    console.log('events');
                    self.eventsLoadingRequest(true);
                    calendarService.getEvents(moment(info.start), moment(info.end)).then(
                        function(result) {
                            ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.events, self.parseByType(result));
                            self.eventsLoadingRequest(false);
                            successCallback(ko.utils.arrayMap(self.events(), function(item) { return item.serialize() }));
                        },
                        function(error) {   
                        }
                    );
                },
                customButtons: {
                    filterEvents: {
                        text: 'Events',
                        click: function() {
                            self.eventsFilter(true, false);
                        }
                    },
                    filterAll: {
                        text: 'All',
                        click: function() {
                            self.eventsFilter(true, true);
                        }
                    },
                    filterGoals: {
                        text: 'Goals',
                        click: function() {
                            self.eventsFilter(false, true);
                        }
                    }
                },
                header: {
                    left: 'title',
                    right: 'prev,today,next dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek, filterEvents,filterAll,filterGoals'
                },
                navLinks: true,
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true
            });
```

And eventsFilter function merges two arrays into one. Is it possible to manually call `events : function(info, successCallback, failureCallback)`?

I want to avoid using multiple streams and reloading events to apply filter.

Comment: _"Is it possible to manually call events : function(info, successCallback, failureCallback)"_ ... effectively yes by running [refetchEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-refetchEvents) - this will cause all events to be taken again from their source. In your case that involves running your "events" function, as fullCalendar is holding that function as the place from which to fetch new events (it will also re-run the function if the user moves to a new date range for which events have not yet been downloaded).

Comment: _"I can't find a method that would just place events from array to screen_" .... try [addEventSource](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEventSource)